# remove a textbox dynamically in jquery without using any javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code, i tried to create dynamically add/remove textbox. when i click the delete button everything is deleted, what should i do (or pls specify my error in this code.) i want to remove one by one.. can anyone tell this to me? Thanks in advance..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>dynamic add button</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>              
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('<button/>').attr({ 'id': 'add' }).appendTo("body");
        $("#add").text("Add Field");
        $('<div/>').attr({ 'id': 'items' }).appendTo("body");
        $('<div/>').attr({ 'type': 'text', 'name': 'input[]' }).appendTo("#items");

        $("#add").click(function (e) {
            //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
            var text1 = $('<div/>').attr({ 'id':'div2','type': 'text', 'name': 'input[]' });
           var text2 = $('<input/>').attr({ 'id': 'i1', 'type': 'text', 'name': 'username', 'size': '25' });
           var text3 = $('<button/>').attr({ 'id': 'del' }).text("Delete");
            $("#div2").append(text2, text3);
            $("#items").append(text1);
            $('<br/>').insertAfter(text3);
        });

        //delete function
        $("body").on("click","#del",function (e) {
            $(this).parent("div").remove();
        });       
    });      
   </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, so "in jquery without using any javascript" doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Try to assign an id for a textbox and delete button when user click on them.I think you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/01qqc5cg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is javascript, but I think this is what you mean. Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfthf2qc/

The problem was that you kept the same id for all of the text fields (`#div2`) so when you appended the new field, jquery kept appending to the first occurrence of `#div2`. Then when you call the delete function, it deletes the parent div which now contains all of your fields.

In my code I created a `count` variable that keeps counting up each time the "add" button was clicked and using it to create unique div names (div1, div2, div3, etc), so jquery knows where to append the new field.

I also moved `$("#items").append(text1);` up before `$("#div" + count).append(text2, text3);` as putting it after makes the first click to the "add" button fail, as it does not have any div containers to append to.

```
    $("#items").append(text1);
    $("#div" + count).append(text2, text3);
    $('<br/>').insertAfter(text3);
```

Personally I think there may be a more elegant solution to this but I didn't want to change your code too much